# Proof Verification: If $D$ is a compact set and $\mathbf{f}\in C(D,\mathbb{E}^m)$, then $||\mathbf{f}||$ must achieve max value and min value on $D$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Here's my attempt at proving this.

*Proof:* Since $D$ is a compact set and $\mathbf{f}$ is a continuous function, $\mathbf{f}(D)$ must also be a compact set. Therefore, $||\mathbf{f}(D)||\leq M$ for some $M\in\mathbb{R}$ because $\mathbf{f}(D)$ is closed and bounded. Hence, it follows that $||\mathbf{f}||$ must achieve minimum value and maximum value on $D$.

Comment: Why not use that $\|f\|$ is continuous?

Comment: Your last sentence just states what you are trying to prove, it does not demonstrate it in any way. You need to show that a continuous function $g$ attains a $\max,\min$ on a compact set. One way it to take a sequence of points $x_n$ such that $g(x_n)$ approaches the $\max $ (or $\min$) and use compactness to deduce something about the sequence $x_n$.

Comment: To denote a norm it is better to use `\|` instead of `||`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you must add that any norm is continuous, that is the map $$f(x)\mapsto \|f(x)\|$$

is continuous, then $\|f(D)\|\subset\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$ is compact provided that $f(D)$ is compact, what implies that by the Heine-Borel theorem it is closed and bounded, what implies that the maximum and minimum of $\|f(D)\|$ exists.

Comment: Can I use the fact that $\|f(x)\| \leq M$ since $f(D)$ is a closed and bounded set? We haven't learned that any norm is continuous yet. I was actually thinking about proving the norm is continuous that it would automatically follow that $\|f\|$ will achieve max and min by Extreme Value Theorem.

Comment: No, you cant. It doesnt care that $f(D)$ is compact if you cant ensure that $(g\circ f)(D)$ is closed and bounded, how you knows that $\|f(x)\|<M$ for all $x\in D$? The continuity of any norm is immediate from the reversed triangle inequality (provided that $\|x\|$ and $\|y\|$ are finite), that is $$\big|\|x\|-\|y\|\big|\le\|x-y\|$$ what implies that the function $\|{\cdot}\|$ is Lipschitz, so it is continuous.